# How to make a canvas circle to rotate as the Earth around the Sun?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

everyone!
I have a challenge. I need to draw a mini-Solar-system on Canvas.
In this system there are 3 circles (the Moon, the Sun and the Earth).
According to the task, the Moon must revolve around the Earth, and the Earth must revolve around the Sun.

These are rotation functions:

```
var drawSun = function(centerX, centerY, radius){
    centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    radius = 150;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    context.stroke();
}

var drawEarth = function(){
    var circle = {centerX:canvas.width/4, centerY:canvas.height/4, radius:50, angle:0}
    var earth = {x:0, y:0,speed:1};
    earth.x = circle.centerX + Math.cos(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
    earth.y = circle.centerY + Math.sin(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
    circle.angle += earth.speed;
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(earth.x, earth.y, 15,0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.closePath();
}

var drawMoon = function(){
    var circle = {centerX:canvas.width / 4, centerY:canvas.height / 4, radius:5, angle:0}
    var moon= {x:0, y:0,speed:1};
    moon.x = circle.centerX + Math.cos(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
    moon.y = circle.centerY + Math.sin(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
    circle.angle += moon.speed;
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
    context.stroke();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(moon.x, moon.y, 15,0, Math.PI*2, true);
    context.closePath();
}

var drawPlanets = function(){
    drawSun();
    drawEarth();
    drawMoon();
}
```

But, to be honest, planets are not moving at all. They are just existing (but only the Sun and the Moon), and their position is static.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   
   void function() {
   
    "use strict";
    
    const _2PI = 2.0 * Math.PI;
    
    class Planet {
     constructor(x,y,radius,colour,parent,orbitDistance,orbitSpeed) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y = 0;
      this.originX = x;
      this.originY = y;
      this.radius = radius;
      this.colour = colour;
      this.parent = parent || null;
      this.orbitDistance = parent ? orbitDistance : 0;
      this.orbitSpeed = parent ? orbitSpeed : 0;
      this.orbitAngle = 0.0;
     }
     
     tick() {
      this.orbitAngle += this.orbitSpeed;
      if (this.orbitAngle > _2PI) {
       this.orbitAngle = 0.0;
      }
      
      this.x = (this.parent ? this.parent.x : this.originX) + Math.cos(this.orbitAngle) * this.orbitDistance;
      this.y = (this.parent ? this.parent.y : this.originY) + Math.sin(this.orbitAngle) * this.orbitDistance;
     }
     
     render(ctx) {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0.0,_2PI,false);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();
     }
    }
    
    let canvasWidth = 180;
    let canvasHeight = 160;
    let canvas = null;
    let ctx = null;
    let sun = null;
    let earth = null;
    let moon = null;
    
    function loop() {
     
     // Update orbits
     sun.tick();
     earth.tick();
     moon.tick();
     
     // Clear canvas
     ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
     
     // Render planets
     sun.render(ctx);
     earth.render(ctx);
     moon.render(ctx);
     
     // Keeps the loop running at 60 fps
     requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    
    window.onload = function() {
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     canvas.width = canvasWidth;
     canvas.height = canvasHeight;
     ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     
     sun = new Planet(90,80,10,"orange");
     earth = new Planet(0,0,5,"blue",sun,60,0.0125);
     moon = new Planet(0,0,3,"#777777",earth,10,0.025);
     
     loop();
    }
   
   }();
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```